# Compare meta_values and return results that are similar

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a Custom Post Type for Properties and on the Single Property Page there is a sidebar that I want to show similar Properties in.

I have managed to show Properties with the same terms but I would also like to return only Properties with the same amount of bedrooms.

How could I do this?

For example this is how I do it to show the Properties with the same terms:

```
$type_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'status');
if(!empty($type_terms) && is_array($type_terms)) {
    $types_array = array();
    foreach($type_terms as $type_term) {
        $types_array[] = $type_term->term_id;
    }
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'status',
        'field'     => 'id',
        'terms'     => $types_array
    );
}
```

What would I have to change to make this work for a `meta_value` that is saved under the `meta_key` called `bedroom`

Answer (score 0):

You've tried with `meta_query`?

```
 $rooms = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bedroom', true );

 $meta_query = array(
      array(
           'key' => 'bedroom',
           'value' => $rooms,
           'compare' => '='
      )
 );
```

[WP_Query documentation on custom field parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)